# SFAuthenticationViewController issue with Google on iOS 11

Tags: ios, google-oauth

I implemented authentication using Google Sign In and everything works correctly.  However, if the user taps Cancel on the Google-generated dialog box that asks the user *"Foo Wants to Use "google.com" to Sign In"*, the app crashes with a 'Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior: SFAuthenticationViewController' error.

I thought maybe I did not implement an optional function in the GIDSignInUIDelegate but I have them implemented and there is nothing in the Google documentation that talks about this possibility (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin).

Does anyone know what I am missing to handle a Cancel press?

Comment: Where do you have your SFAuthenticationViewController defined ?

Comment: Just figured it out, forgot to add: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self    method. I saw the GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self in the documentation but there is also the delegate that needs to be set.

Comment: Make sense, usually this sort of error occurs when the viewcontroller you are trying to reach may not have any reference. cheers

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was doing popToRoot back navigation, so I have been set `delegate` and `presentingViewController` on viewDidLoad() but actually when I come back there is no reference for `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate` and `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController`.
 Simply I wrote code on google login button action:

```
@IBAction func buttonHandlerGoogle(_ sender: Any) {

//===These lines added for the reference=========
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self
//===============================================

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
```